# Namespace issue between class in project and gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, namespaces, rubygems, twilio

So, I have run into an interesting issue. In my project, I have a class called "Builder". We have been running this app for years and recently we realized we needed [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/ruby). This requires the Builder gem (https://github.com/jimweirich/builder). The problem I am having is that there is an overwriting of the names. What can I do to ensure I can use twilio and continue with my builder class? What is the path of least resistance for this namespace nightmare?

Comment: What does your Builder builds? I'd solve this by the simple procedure of renaming it to SomethingBuilder. If it builds apps, for instance, I would name it AppBuilder and go on with my project.

Comment: Your project's classes should all be namespaced under a module with the same name as your project, e.g. if your project is called Foo, you'll have Foo::Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to avoid namespace clashes is to use a namespace of your own:

```
module MyApp
  class Builder
  end
end
```

Thats basically how all worthwhile ruby gems are written as it makes interoperateablilty possible. Namespacing stuff that goes in the `/lib` directory of your rails app is pretty painless. But namespacing all your controllers, models etc. is less pleasant. It kills a good part of the "it just works" rails magic.

Explicity namespacing stuff like:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    resources :things
  end
end
```

Is pretty straight forward. However transparently namespacing is quite a bit trickier - that is placing the code in a module without significantly changing routes, path helpers or database table names.

You can namespace controllers with:

```
scope module: 'my_app' do
  resources :things
end
```

Which would route to `MyApp::ThingsController` without affecting the path or helpers. You would place the controller in  `app/controllers/my_app/things_controller.rb`.

Comment: Where would you suggest I change this? In which file?

Comment: Because I need to do an application wide namespace it would seem. All controllers, all models, everything. Sadly this wasn't foreseen back when this was developed. But I need to change as little interior code as possible. It's too late in the game to overhaul and fix everything and I am not the owner of the project.

Comment: Maybe all you need is to namespace the Builder class - in that case you would add a module which wraps the class and move it to /lib/my_app/builder.rb